# which would be more memory efficient?

Tags: java, memory-management

Consider this value object `Myclass` which has following members.
There would be hundred-thousands of `MyClass` instances.

Optional fields would have about 50% population.

All optional would either be populated or they will not.

which is more efficient for memory?

1.

```
    class MyClass{
      String mandatory1;
      int mandatory2;
      double mandatory3;

      String optional1;
      int optional2;
      double optional3;
      //lets say there are 10+ like these
}
```

2. Wrap optional fields in a DS and set it as null when optional value are not present.

```
    class MyClass{
      String mandatory1;
      int mandatory2;
      double mandatory3;

     OptionalParams params;
}
```

Question - 
Does wrapping up in DS wont set the null references for the members within ? **So effectively one null reference vs 10+ null references ?**

I understand that with null values it doesn't matter much but i do care about the memory used by references ?

Comment: Try both and find out?  Or by more RAM and don't worry about it?

Comment: why do you need hundreds of thousands of instances of a class?

Comment: I want to understand the memory allocation with wrapper/loose objects. Looking for some reference. Thx in adv.

Comment: @TimCastelijns its  a value object, you can have multi million such data.. Why surprised ?